# Java Help - ActionListener not working

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

I am very new to Java,
I am trying to make the **static class Action implements ActionListener** work but no matter what I do,  it pretty much doesn't work.

Can someone please help me ?

```
 package kod.main;

 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class FoodMenu {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

   //JFrame   
   JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Hello");
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setSize(500,500);
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   frame.add(panel);
   JButton button = new JButton("Start Game");
   panel.add(button);
 }
 static class Action implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPreformed (ActionEvent e){
        JFrame Frame2 = new JFrame ("Clicked");
        Frame2.setVisible(true);
        Frame2.setSize(200,200);
        JLabel lable = new JLabel("Success !");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I click it , it dosen't work

Comment: you need a debug, console or something like that.

Comment: The code doesn't even compile. Why do you try to execute code that doesn't compile?

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled the interface method... It is "actionPerformed" not "actionPreformed". Use the Override annotation, and it would have told you.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JFrame Frame2 = new JFrame("Clicked");
  Frame2.setVisible(true);
  Frame2.setSize(200, 200);
  JLabel lable = new JLabel("Success !");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, new to English too ...

Comment: *"new to English too"*  This problem is not limited to people whose native language is not English.  I am a native speaker of English but often make typos. that wreck things in the same way.  Fortunately Elliot provided a powerful way to check - `@Override`.  Discover how it works, and always use it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you've spelt `actionPerformed` wrong in your Action class.

You also haven't registered an instance of your ActionListener to any of your components. You can add the following to your main method, assuming that you want to perform what action you have written when `button` is pressed.

```
button.addActionListener(new Action());
```